# Evaluate $\int_\gamma\left(\sqrt{x^2-y}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-y}}\right)dx-\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2-y}} \ dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Evaluate
>    $$I=\int_\gamma\left(\sqrt{x^2-y}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-y}}\right)dx-\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2-y}}
>  \ dy,$$
>
> where $\gamma$ is a part of the curve $x=y^2$ from $(1,-1)$ to
>   $(4,-2).$

Parameterizing by

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x & = & t \\
    y & = & -t^2 \\
  \end{array}
\right.\implies \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    dx & = & dt \\
    dy & = & -2t \ dt \\
  \end{array}
\right., \quad t\in[1,2].$$

So,

$$
\begin{align}
I
&=\int_\gamma \sqrt{t^2+t^2} + \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+t^2}}+\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+t^2}} \ dt\\
&=\int_\gamma |t|\sqrt{2}+\frac{t(t^2+1)}{|t|\sqrt{2}} \ dt \quad (|t|=t, \ t\geq0.)\\
&=\int_1^2 t\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(t^2+1) \ dt = \frac{19\sqrt{2}}{6}.
\end{align} 
$$

Correct anser is $11\sqrt{2}.$ What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Your parametrization is wrong.  You want $x=y^2$, but $(x,y)=(t,-t^2)$ does not satisfy that (and it's also unclear why you have $t$ going from $1$ to $2$).  You could instead parametrize it as $(x,y)=(t^2,-t)$ for $t$ going from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Indeed the parametrization is incorrect. With your suggestion I get the integral $$\int_1^2 \frac{8t^5+5t^2}{2\sqrt{t^4+t}} \ dt=11\sqrt{2}.$$ I can't evaluate this integral. Should I maybe use another method of solving this problem so I don't have to deal with the above integral?